# How to create simple JSON API, e.g. with Jetty?

Tags: json, jetty

this seems pretty basic, but I am rather new to web development so I am a bit stuck here. I have MongoDB running on the backend, which contains geo-spatial objects that in the front end should be displayed on a map. The communication between backend and web frontend is where I have knowledge gaps.

The user should be able to zoom to an area on a map that he is interested in, then press "Search". The backend would then find every entry in the database that has coordinates that are on the users current screen. It would transmit these to the frontend, ideally as a list of JSON objects. The frontend displays these on a map.

I have a front end mock up, code that puts data into MongoDB and code that queries MongoDB. I know that I am missing a server that can be queried from the frontend. I thought I use Jetty. But what do I need to do then? I guess I need Jetty to provide a JSON API that I can query from JavaScript. Could someone point me to the Jetty class or interface that I need to implement and maybe give a few lines of code on how to query this from JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a very open question here.

To start with, Jetty is merely a Java Web Container (following a subset of the Java EE Web Profile), while it does have some [AJAX/JSON capabilities](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/index.html?org/eclipse/jetty/util/ajax/package-summary.html), it is extremely fundamental and not hooked up into any sort of query API.

You would do better do use Jetty along with a proper REST/JSON API library for your project.

Some examples (these are not the only choices available):

- [jersey](/questions/tagged/jersey) - [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/) - an Open Source JAX-RS (JSR 311) implementation for RESTful web services, with [JSON Support](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json) - Here's [Lars Vogel's Tutorial on JAX-RS using Jersey](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html).
- [restlet](/questions/tagged/restlet) - [Restlet](http://restlet.org/) - another RESTful web API, with a [JSON extension](http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/extensions/json)
- [resteasy](/questions/tagged/resteasy) - [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy) - another JAX-RS implementation for RESTful web services, with [JSON marshalling](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.6.Final/userguide/html/Built_in_JAXB_providers.html#JAXB_+_JSON_provider).

Also note that there are many flavors of Java based [JSON APIs and Libraries](http://json.org/), you should probably be aware of them as you will encounter them in your journey to success.

Comment: Hi, i don't understand why json must use jersey (or similar) and cannot be done by response.getwriter.write(a json string here).

Comment: @Tiina you can certainly use that technique, you'll be in more control, but you'll also wind up reimplementing much of what jersey/restlet/resteasy have already done.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I found the Dropwizard framework (there might be others), which does a lot of the work that is necessary to get a simple JSON API up out of the box:

http://dropwizard.io/